# Appending to a ul before an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a year list dynamically and I am truncating the list and displaying a "show more" and a "show less" link after the list of years. If I `append` the years to the `ul`, the years come after the "show more/less" links, and if I `prepend` the years, they show before the "show more/less" links but are in reverse order.

Is there a way for me to append the years to the ul but to append them, in chronological order, before the "show more/less" links?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2014</a></li>');
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2015</a></li>');  
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2016</a></li>');  
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2017</a></li>');
  
  $('.years-prepend').prepend('<li><a href="#">2014</a></li>');
  $('.years-prepend').prepend('<li><a href="#">2015</a></li>');  
  $('.years-prepend').prepend('<li><a href="#">2016</a></li>');  
  $('.years-prepend').prepend('<li><a href="#">2017</a></li>'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Appending - Years are in correct order, but more/less links come BEFORE years</h2>
<ul class="years-append">
 <a class="btn-more" href="#"><span>+</span> More</a>
 <a class="btn-less" href="#"><span>-</span> Less</a>
</ul>

<h2>Prepending - more/less links come AFTER years, but years are in reverse order</h2>
<ul class="years-prepend">
    <!-- These links should come after the list of years, years should be in chronological order -->
 <a class="btn-more" href="#"><span>+</span> More</a>
 <a class="btn-less" href="#"><span>-</span> Less</a>
</ul>
```

Sorry if the wording is confusing, let me know if I need to clarify more.

Comment: You realize that you can't just have floating anchor tags inside a `ul` tag, right? The **only** tag that can be inside a `ul` is an `li` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not changing the HTML? It's the easiest way to achieve what you want. And your HTML is not valid by the way. It's not valid to have `<a>` directly within a `<ul>`

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul class="years-append"></ul>
  <a class="btn-more" href="#"><span>+</span> More</a>
  <a class="btn-less" href="#"><span>-</span> Less</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript (untouched):

```
$(function() {
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2014</a></li>');
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2015</a></li>');  
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2016</a></li>');  
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2017</a></li>');
});
```

Explanation: Before you start scripting and styling you should try to bring the HTML in a logical order. In this case we *mark* the list and the buttons to belong together by setting them into a `<div>`. As the list should show up before the buttons, it's also in the HTML like that.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8nz3pwtk/

Answer (score 1):

[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds the element to the end of the parent element, while [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) adds it to the start. The show more and less links in your example are displaying above the year list because append is appending the years *after* those links. The reason prepend is showing the years in reverse order is because you are prepending 2014, then prepending 2015, which would put it before 2014, etc.

You should place the Show more/less links outside of the list, and use append. This will put the years in order, and also fix the fact that you should not be placing `a` elements inside a `ul`. 
Source: http://w3c.github.io/html/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element

```js
$(function() {
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2014</a></li>');
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2015</a></li>');  
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2016</a></li>');  
  $('.years-append').append('<li><a href="#">2017</a></li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="years-append">
 
</ul>
<a class="btn-more" href="#"><span>+</span> More</a>
<a class="btn-less" href="#"><span>-</span> Less</a>
```